# Serialization: How to get unique name for each element in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

While serializing a class i am getting xml in this format.

```
<Root Name="blah">
  <Element>1</Element>
  <Element>2</Element>
  <Element>3</Element>
  <Element>4</Element>
</root>
```

My class is

```
public class Root
{
    public List<data> Element { get; set; }
}
```

But i need data in format:

```
<Root Name="blah">
  <Element0>1</Element0>
  <Element1>2</Element1>
  <Element2>3</Element2>
  <Element3>4</Element3>
</root>
```

Please help...

Comment: Looks strange, why you need that? What about having unique elemtn attribute value rather than name? For instance `<Elemend Id="1">1</Element>`

Comment: I can't see how this could even work with different Object Names. I wonder, why you even need it in that format.

Comment: Form your own xml with XDocument or XmlDocument

Comment: Just curious, why would you want this?

Comment: I am working on jQuery.sheet, that needs data in this format.

Check this: http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet

Comment: This looks like the format was devised by someone who didn't know how to work with XML properly. I would advise you to fix the format.

Comment: You could transform your serialized Xml to the desired "format" using Xslt, but as others stated before you should rethink what you are about to do. It smells like you are about to do plain text parsing to your Xml which is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

This simply isn't a good fit for the regular serializers; and implementing IXmlSerializable is overkill.

Just create a DOM for what you need; a good place to start would be XElement:

```
var el = new XElement(
    new XAttribute("Name", obj.Name),
    obj.Element.Select((i,child) =>
        new XElement("Element" + i, child))
);
var xml = el.ToString();
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it automatically using XML serializer.

Are you sure that setting the nodes' number wouldn't be acceptable as an attribute, or maybe breaking your  node up to the following syntax?

```
<Element>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Value>1</Value>
</Element>
```